# Number.parseInt(input, 2); does not show the binary value after 2 when the input is in decimal

Tags: javascript, console.log, parseint

This is the code:

```js
var input = prompt("Enter a decimal value");

console.log(input +" the binary value would be:", Number.parseInt(input, 2));
```

The output for 1 & 2 is correct but from 3 onwards it displays NaN.

It works with this code:

```js
var input = Number(prompt("Enter a decimal value"));

console.log(input +" the binary value would be:", input.toString(input, 2));
```

I want to know why it doesn't work with the 1st code.

Comment: Your 2nd code produce 10 for 3.

Comment: Nothing to do with it being a string @Alex since thats what parseInt expects

Comment: The problem is the radix is 2 as in binary, yet the OP is not passing a binary string to get the decimal equivalent.

Comment: i put a higher number with your second test and `Uncaught RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36`.. things getting interesting

Comment: @TheBombSquad it's because they're passing the input as the radix. Neither code example is actually doing what the user seems to be expecting it to.

Answer (score 2):

FIrst of all the way you want to convert to binary is not right. You can use `input.toString(2)` to convert decimal to binary. But before that you have to convert your input to a number as the prompt will return a string.

You can do the following,

```js
var input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a decimal value"));

console.log(input +" the binary value would be:",input.toString(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [MDN docs for parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
> specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
> returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

And then,

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number with the radix
> in use, parseInt returns NaN.

Any string containing anything other than a zero or one as the first character will return `NaN`.

So inputing 11111 or 101010101 will work, but 2 or 3 or 333 won't.

Answer (score 2):

Your two pieces of code do more or less the opposite of each other.

> ```
> Number.parseInt(input, 2)
> ```

… expects `input` to be a string containing a binary number, which it converts into a JavaScript Number.

If you type a `2` then that isn't a valid binary number (which only has `0`s and `1`s.

---

> ```
> input.toString(input, 2)
> ```

… is just wrong

```
input.toString(2)
```

… expects `input` to be a JavaScript Number and it converts it to a string containing a decimal representation of that.

---

Compare:

```js
console.log("Parse binary numbers");
console.log(Number.parseInt("1", 2));
console.log(Number.parseInt("10", 2));
console.log(Number.parseInt("3", 2));

console.log("Convert numbers to binary");
console.log(1.0.toString(2))
console.log(2.0.toString(2))
console.log(3.0.toString(2))
```

Comment: You can just write `1..toString(2)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt

So, Number.parseInt does not convert to binary but converts from binary. If you input 3, you receive NaN because 3 is not a possible digit parsing from base 2 to base 10.

If you instead ran this code...

```js
var input = prompt("Enter a decimal value");

console.log(input +" the binary value would be:", Number.parseInt(input, 2));
```

and input '101' you'd receive 5, because we're converting from binary to decimal.